# getting global IP address when using a vpn

Tags: c++, sockets

How can I get my global IP address? I can see my global IP address via a site: www.whatismyipaddress.com

It shows correctly about information of my computer including IP address.
But if I use a VPN it is not correct.
How can I get base global IP address?

More Info:
I have multi Lan card.

I use VPN.

OS: Windows 7

Dev Tool: Visual Studio 2008

Dev Lang: c++/mfc

Comment: What do you mean by "base"?

Comment: just not use vpn state ip address

Comment: What do you mean the IP you see when connected to VPN is "not correct"? It is. That is the IP you're showing the outside world at that moment.

Comment: Seen from the outside world: Your machine is behind a `NAT`ting device?

Comment: when without using vpn: my address is X.X.X.X, but using vpn: my address is changed with Y.Y.Y.Y

Comment: Dear Alk I don't know ur question correctly. I am not a network pro

Comment: which ip address(es) do you see when doing `ipconfig` in a `cmd` window?

Comment: Ipconfig address is not same with getting address via site, I think ipconfig is my localaddress and site is route address. And if vpn connected ipconfig address is also changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more network interfaces, you have more IP addresses. 
Actual IP address for a connection is chosen primarily by the target:

If you connect to localhost, you'll probably be connected as 127.0.0.1.

If you connect to some host in your vpn, you'll have IP from your VPN interface.

If you connect to some host in the internet, you'll have IP address of the interface responsible for the internet connection.

The IP address you see on a website is influenced by what is the setting of the VPN: If all trafic is passed through that VPN then you have VPN Interface's address - that's obvious. Check your internet [explorer] setting, if there isn't any proxy set by VPN and check your routing tables when the VPN is connected and disconected. That will answer all your questions.

Comment: teach me how can i check my routing tables

Comment: try `route print` for start, and later you can continue with advice from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110793/is-there-a-c-c-api-to-the-route-information-on-windows)

Comment: I've seen route print and I cannot find out ip address without using vpn. But I can find out main iterface mac-address.
I think we can find out my main ip address via main interface mac address